# COM порт как отправить несколько бит?

Tags: c#

Нужно отправить `AA 02`

Думаю это биты. Не слать же текстом, нужно это как то преобразовать?

И как определить что пришло?

получаю строку

> responseData .??>??>??% ??  %

что пришло

```
                inData += sp.ReadExisting();
                byte[] decBytes1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inData);
                string all = BitConverter.ToString(decBytes1);
                logger.Debug("inData " + all);
```

Comment: а в чем проблема отправки строкой?  

`SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();`  

`var atCommand = "AT\n";`  
`sp.WriteLine(atCommand);`

Comment: @Bald56rus: `"AA" != 0xAA`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin *"Думаю это биты"* - пытаюсь отправить то не знаю что а может это `hex` строка в кодировке *UCS2* а может в `7Bit` кодировке. это я к тому что попытка привести что то к чему то бессмысленна

Comment: может Вы дадите уточнения что Вы пытаетесь сделать?!

Comment: @Bald56rus: ага, понял вас.

Comment: из доки: запрос текущих значений у прибора ЭХО-Р 02:  AA 02

Comment: С учетом обновления вопроса - в документации должно быть четко сказано какой длины должен быть ответ, как должен быть сформирован пакет. Прочитайте лучше все с начала до конца. А потом уже задавайте вопросы.

Comment: ответ: 04 47 3C 3E 13 A1 AF 3C 00 46 04 00 E0 7E 00 00 02 00 FF DD но я тут этих значений не вижу

Comment: @des1roer, суть в том - что в документации должно быть сказано за что конкретно отвечают байты ответа. Ну к примеру 04 47 - ответ от первого датчика,  3C 3E 13 A1 - ответ от второго и т.д. Без документации вы просто не разберете ответ.

Comment: там это тоже указано. мне бы посмотреть всю строку для начала а получаю фиг знает чо. это конвертировать надо или что?

Comment: На этот вопрос тоже должна ответить документация. Везде по разному. Где то ответы читаются в signed\unsigned 16\32\64, где то побайтно. Никто не знает и врятли тут кто либо работал конкретно с этим прибором.

Comment: зря Вы пытаетесь декодировать пришедшую строку в `UTF8` скорее следует использовать `ASCII` и как Вам правильно заметил @z668 надо знать как расшифровать строку пришедшую в ответ

Comment: @Bald56rus, это верно если ответ приходит строкой. А если ответ содержит несколько числовых параметров? Не стоит путать ТС, пусть читает и вникает в документацию, за него это никто делать не будет.

Comment: вот про аски ничего не сказано. но полученный ответ похож на правду

Comment: @des1roer    Как отправить вам уже подсказали, а по поводу чтения - если вам нужно считать байты не используйте функцию `ReadExisting` так как она сразу конвертирует значения в символы. Используйте функцию `ReadByte` и добавляйте каждый считанный символ в массив байт или в `List`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конвертация HEX строки в массив байт

```
public byte[] StrToByteArr(string hexStr) 
{
    hexStr = hexStr.Replace(" ", "");
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hexStr.Length)
                     .Where(a => a % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(a => Convert.ToByte(hexStr.Substring(a, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

Отправка:

```
var serialPort = new SerialPort();
var str = "AA 02";
serialPort.Write(StrToByteArr(str), 0, str.Split(' ').Length);
```

**UPD:** Переделал отправку на более правельную

```
var serialPort = new SerialPort();
var str = "AA 02";
var bArr = StrToByteArr(str)
serialPort.Write(bArr, 0, bArr.Length);
```

Comment: @Bald56rus, задача стояла отправить :) про завершать не говорилось :)

Comment: а byte[] data = { 0xAA, 0x02 }; не пройдет?

Comment: пройдет, но вам же строка нужна судя из описания

Comment: @des1roer писал по памяти, поэтому возможно, ща в студии погляжу

Comment: судя из описания я должен отправить биты

Answer (score -1):

Парсинг из строки... да вы что, издеваетесь?!

```
serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 0xaa, 0x02 }, 0, 2)
```

А ответ лучше всего посмотреть отладчиком.

Comment: парсинг строки необходим при интерактивной отправке. когда команда вводится через строку ввода или получается через командную строчку.

Comment: @Dmitry автору вопроса нужно было отправить конкретные 2 байта из документации. Где было хоть слово про командную строку или интерактивный режим?

Comment: Павел, вторая строчка *Не слать же текстом, нужно это как то преобразовать?* четко говорит нам о том, что надо бы из строки преобразовать, а потом уже слать. А уж из строки или как то по другому, не так уж и важно

Comment: @Dmitry эта строчка гооврит лишь о том, что автор даже не представляет с какой стороны подойти к задаче...

Comment: Павел, но она таки есть

Answer (score -2):

Преобразуйте их в массив Byte и посылайте через SerialPort.

Comment: соль в том как byte[] data = { new Byte["AA"], new Byte['AA'] }; чет не работает

Comment: Так преобразование неверное. byte.Parse("AA") - так правильно.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/43952)

Comment: @Spawn зря вы так. Это был все-таки именно ответ на вопрос, пусть и некачественный